# How do I remove the foreach from this linq code?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, viewmodel

I'm fairly new at MVC and linq and viewmodels in particular. I managed to get a create and index views to work. The "insert" wasn't as hard as the "list".

I have this linq query:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            List<BlendElVM> BEVM = new List<BlendElVM>();
            var list = (from Blend in db.blends
                        join BlendEl in db.blendEl on Blend.ID equals BlendEl.ID
                        select new
                        {
                            Blend.ID, Blend.Title, Blend.TransDt, BlendEl.Comment
                        }).ToList();

             foreach (var item in list)
              {
                  BlendElVM o = new BlendElVM(); // ViewModel
                  o.Comment = item.Comment;
                  o.Title = item.Title;
                  o.TransDt = item.TransDt;
                  o.ID = item.ID;
                  BEVM.Add(o);
              }
            return View(BEVM);           
        }
```

What I'm not sure about is the "foreach" section. When I'm running in debug, the "list" shows up fine, but if I comment out the "foreach" I get an error - ie not expecting the model. What does the foreach do? It has to do with the database, but I don't understand the where it is using the "o" and setting the columns. I thought it would all be in one linq query. Is it possible to combine the two and eliminate the "foreach"?

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Comment: You query is creating a collection of anonymous objects. You view expects a collection of `BlendElVM`, so the loop is just generating the collection of that object based on the values your query returns - you don't necessarily need it - you can project the query into the view model as per Robert Harvey's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
        var BEVM  = (from blend in db.blends
                    join BlendEl in db.blendEl on Blend.ID equals BlendEl.ID
                    select new BlendELVM
                    {
                        ID = blend.ID, 
                        Title = blend.Title, 
                        TransDT = blend.TransDt, 
                        comment = blendEl.Comment
                    }).ToList();
```

Comment: Keep in mind that if you do this against a DB Queryable, you can use this approach as long as BlendELVM only contains primitive types (Strings, ints, datetimes, bools, etc.). Complex properties are not allowed, not even if they don't assign them.

Comment: I corrected the spelling in the query, but now I get a new issue: "The entity or complex type 'vmTwo.Models.BlendElVM' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query. "  Do I still have to keep the foreach to work?

Comment: You can convert the foreach to a select, as in `var BEVM = list.Select(new BlendELVM
                    {
                        ID = blend.ID, 
                        Title = blend.Title, 
                        TransDT = blend.TransDt, 
                        comment = blendEl.Comment
                    }).ToList();`

Comment: where does that fit in? is it just from the "select new BlendElVM.." or does that replace the whole thing (the "join" etc..)

Comment: Just so I understand..If I have 2 tables, say, inventory and product. And let's say most of the "columns" are in inventory, but I would like a "join" to add the product description. Wouldn't I ALWAYS have to use a collection of anonymous objects in inventory and product? Is there another way? Would Expando work better? What about AutoMapper ? There's just so much I don't know about..

Comment: The only relevant issue here is that you can't project directly into a BlendELVM object directly from EF, due to a limitation in the Linq provider for EF.  That's why the original `foreach` is there, to translate between the anonymous objects and your BlendELVM objects.  There are probably several alternative ways to do it, but at the end of the day the `foreach` or another `select` is probably as good an approach as any.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the foreach is needed in order to read every element in the object so in this case you have:

`BlendElVM o = new BlendElVM();`

So you're creating and object named " o " of the type BlendELVM and this object contains all the attributes that you declared before which are: ID, Title, TransDT, etc

When you put:

```
foreach (var item in list)
          {
              BlendElVM o = new BlendElVM(); // ViewModel
              o.Comment = item.Comment;
              o.Title = item.Title;
              o.TransDt = item.TransDt;
              o.ID = item.ID;
              BEVM.Add(o);
          }
```

You're assigning to the new object o the item that you're reading in the list and in the end adding it to the BVEM list and answering if you can combine them i will say no because at first you're declaring the query and then you're reading the items on the list and assining them to the BEVM list